# Column operators regarding only specific columns (specific dates and code i.e.) in R

Tags: r, data.table

i am trying to calculate the average_relative_humidity of the city Seoul for the dates 2020-01-01 tll 2020-31-01.
I have this data:

[image]

and I´ve tried this already but don´t really know what´missing.

```
Seoul_weather_dt <- Corona_relevant_weather_dt[, avg_relative_humidity_seoul := mean(avg_relative_humidity[code =="2020-01-01":"2020-01-01"]), by = c("province", "date", "avg_temp", "avg_relative_humidity"]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't share data as images, but as code that reproduces your `data.frame`. `dput()` is a useful function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#select only Seoul and relevant dates
Seoul_weather_dt <- Corona_relevant_weather_dt[province == "Seoul" & date > as.date("2020-01-01") & date <= as.date("2020-31-01")]

#calculate average humidity for each unique date
aggregate(Seoul_weather_dt$avg_relative_humidity, by = list(Seoul_weather_dt$date), FUN = mean)
```

The line of code you provide is pretty long. I would suggest creating multiple lines with less functions per line to maintain an overview (also easier when getting an error). Also

- is `date`in class "Date"? You can see that using `str(Seoul_weather_dt)`
- `code =="2020-01-01":"2020-01-01"` only selects one day
- Using `by = c("province", "date", "avg_temp", "avg_relative_humidity")` is strange. Then you would calculate a mean value for each observation of avg_relative_humidity as well, which is not what you want
- Why create average values for each province when you are only interested in Seoul?

Comment: Hey maarvd, thanks a lot for your answer!
I think this is exactly what I want to do. 
I have some problems running the code because I get the errors that  it is an incompatible method ("<=.Date", "Ops.date") for  "<=", i guess for the date.

Comment: Can you share your data using dput()? and provide the results of str(Seoul_weather_dt)?

Comment: I just didn´t transformed the date column to date. I transformed the column to date via as.date(Corona_relevant_weather_dt$date) and then ommited the as.date() in the first code line you provided. And it worked that way. 
Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, goodluck with your project!